# ExpressJS + AngularJS single page without template not found page (404)

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

My application does not load templates in ng-view inside the index.thml.
I let my code here because i am lost.

```
app.js

    var express = require('express');
    var app =  express();
    var path = require('path');
    var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

    // var $ = require('jquery');
    // global.jQuery = $;
    // var bootstrap = require('bootstrap');
    app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

    app.set('views', __dirname + 'views');
    app.set('view engine', 'html');

    var routes = require('./routes');

    app.use(bodyParser.json());
    app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
        extended: true
    }));

    app.get('/', function(req, res) {
      res.sendFile(__dirname + "/public/views/index.html"); 
    });

    app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000);

    var server = app.listen(app.get('port'), function() {
        console.log('Started Success http://localhost:' + server.address().port);
    });
```

And angular route

```
angular.module('geradorContrato', ['ngRoute'])
.config(function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {

$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);

$routeProvider

.when('/contrato', {
    templateUrl: '/public/views/contrato.html',
    controller: 'ContratoController'
})

.when('/contratante', {
    templateUrl: '/public/views/contratante.html',
    controller: 'ContratanteController'
})

.when('/contratada', {
    templateUrl: '/public/views/contratada.html',
    controller: 'ContratadaController'
})

.when('/bemvindo', {
    templateUrl: 'public/views/bemVindo.html',
});

});
```

But when i access http://localhost:3000/#/bemvindo
The page index.html loading success, but ngview not load and showing the message Cannot GET /public/views/bemVindo.html into console network chrome

Below is my index.html

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="geradorContrato">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <base href="/">
        <link rel='stylesheet' href='/stylesheets/dist/css/bootstrap-theme.css'>
        <link rel='stylesheet' href='/stylesheets/dist/css/bootstrap.css'>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/stylesheets/mainStyle.css">

        <script src="/javascript/lib/angular.js"></script>
        <script src="/javascript/lib/angular-route.js"></script>
        <script src="/javascript/lib/jquery.js"></script>
        <script src="/javascript/lib/bootstrap.js"></script>
         <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.3/angular-animate.js"></script>
        <script src="/javascript/main.js"></script>
        <script src="/javascript/ContratoController.js"></script>

        <title>Cadastro</title>
    <head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <ng-view></ng-view>
        </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

and below is my page simple bemVindo.html

## OLÁ SEJA VEM VINDO!

This is base structure my app

[Structure](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/31888880/stackoverflow.png)

Sorry guys, if you do not understand something tell me pl

sorry for my english

### Suggestions

**deek:**

```
var express = require('express');
var app =  express();
var path = require('path');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

var routes = require('./routes');

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
    extended: true
}));

app.use('/', express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/public/views/index.html')));

app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000);

var server = app.listen(app.get('port'), function() {
    console.log('Started Success http://localhost:' + server.address().port);
});
```

**Error Cannot GET /**

Comment: remove public from the templateUrls and see if that works `/public/views/contratante.html'` to `/views/contratante.html'`

Comment: I try, but not work. Its the same

Comment: @BabajideFowotade After many changes. I resolved change again what you said and I get Success. Very nice! I think that with the changes Deek and BabajideFowotade I resolved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

path you have given must be wrong, check for the path where your file resides, try to console the path in the javascript console and provide the right path. "Cannot GET /public/views/bemVindo.html" means that the file bemVindo.html is not in the folder /public/views. It is not able to find the file hence showing this error.

Answer (score 0):

Get rid of :

```
app.set('views', __dirname + 'views');
app.set('view engine', 'html');
```

Not needed....view engine html is default. Views folder isn't used.

EDIT: remove this too:

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
```

Change this:

```
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
  res.sendFile(__dirname + "/public/views/index.html"); 
});
```

To this:

```
app.use('/', express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/public/views/index.html')));
```

Let's express know this is a static directory where the html and supporting files are.

Express will treat it like a normal html directory and try to find an index file. From your index file, the angular will take over routing.

If you wanted to utilize express and templates for routing, the way you did it is best.

You set views folder if you want express to load template files from it but you have none.

You can mix and match with angular too.

Comment: I try, but the aplication does not find root. When I access localhost:3000/  "Cannot GET / "

Comment: I changed my code, but the message a get is Cannot GET /

Comment: did you remove all that I suggested first?

Comment: Yes, Look the code in my question i changed in suggestions

Comment: one more thing to remove:

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

Comment: If I remove app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')) my files JS are not found in page. error 404 for each file

Comment: You need to have the directory correct....I di not know your file structure, please add to answer